# Open app using gmail app invite iOS

Tags: ios, google-app-invites

I am integrating Gmail App Invite in my app. i m successfully receiving invite email which provide "install" link to install/open app.But when i click on install link , it alway opens iTunes in browser though my app is installed on my device. I m referring this link "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html".
Any help will be appreciated. Note: My app is not live.It's not there on iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code in info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.App</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>app</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and for handle add below code in your appdelegate.m file

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://"]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ituneslinkifuhave"]];
}
```

and for testing open your safari browser and run **app://**.

Comment: @Aqua after used please inform me its helped or not